# On the compact embedding of Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sobolev-spaces

In dimension three, we know that the Sobolev space $W^{\frac{13}{11},11}(D)$ is compactly embedded into $W^{1,11}(D)$, where $D$ is a bounded domain in $R^3$ with smooth boundary. **My question** is: Does the dual space $(W^{1,11}(\mathcal {O}))^*$ embed compactly into the dual space $ (W^{\frac{13}{11},11}(\mathcal {O}))^*$?

Answer (score 3):

If $i:X\to Y$ is compact, so is $i^*:Y^*\to X^*$; moreover since here $i$  is dense,  $i^*$ is injective.